# Generate a Universal-binary-function Lookup Table

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

<sub>This is tangentially related to my quest to [invent an esoteric programming language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/4912/2161).</sub>

A table of the binary numbers 0 .. 15 can be used to implement a Universal Binary Function using indexing operations. Given two 1-bit inputs X and Y, *all* 16 possible functions can be encoded in a 4-bit opcode.

```
X Y  F|0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
- -    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  
0 0    0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1    0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 0    0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
       -     -   - -   -   -   -   - -
       0    ~X  ~Y ^   &   Y   X   | 1
      ZERO    NOT-Y   AND         OR
          NOT-X   XOR              ONE
```

So this set of 16 functions can be applied to binary inputs as the function

> *U(f,x,y): (f >> ((x<<1) | y)) & 1*,

or

> *U(f,x,y): (f / 2^(x×2 + y)) % 2*,

or with indexing or matrix partitioning.

It will be useful to know the most compact way to represent or generate such a table of values for any possible languages to be built upon this type of binary operation.

### The goal:

Generate this exact text output:

```
0101010101010101
0011001100110011
0000111100001111
0000000011111111
```

That's it! Shortest-code wins.

Comment: I had an intuition that the APL-family would do well here. :)

Comment: Also related: [A simple logic gate calculator](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12783/3918)

Comment: Are leading or trailing newlines accepted?

Comment: Yes, extra newlines are fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### J, 10 (13?) characters

```
|.|:#:i.16
```

Number list:

```
   i.16
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15`
```

to binary:

```
   #:i.16
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

Transpose:

```
   |:#:i.16
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Reverse:

```
   |.|:#:i.16
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Do we need to remove the spaces? Looking at the other J answer it seems we do so we'll need to add 3 characters and borrow the `1":` from [Jan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12109/737).

Comment: Very nice style of explanation. +1 (damn short, too!)

Comment: As soon as I saw [Peter's Golfscript answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) I knew I could have done much better. Well, you had already done it.

Comment: Nice to see something shorter than Golfscript...

Comment: [Reimplemented your solution in postscript](https://gist.github.com/luser-dr00g/9382217)

Comment: @luserdroog Wow. That's a lot of code. Much more readable than the J source code though. :-) Very cool.

Comment: It can probably be factored and improved considerably. It looks like I wrote the reverse function twice, as `|.` and `@`!

Answer (score 13):

### Python 2, 40

```
for n in 1,2,4,8:print 8/n*('0'*n+'1'*n)
```

Answer (score 7):

### APL (14)

Assuming `⎕IO=0` (that's a setting):

```
⎕D[⊖(4⍴2)⊤⍳16]
```

Explanation:

- `⍳16`: numbers [0,16)
- `(4⍴2)⊤`: encode each number in base 2 using 4 digits
- `⊖`: horizontal reverse (so the MSB ends up on top)
- `⎕D[`...`]`: select these values from `⎕D` which is the string `0123456789`. (A numeric matrix is displayed with spaces between the values, a character matrix is not. So this converts each numerical bit to one of the chars `'0' '1'`).

Comment: Is the first character in the source supposed to look like a square, or am I still missing some fonts?

Comment: @TimSeguine Yes, it's a square, called *quad* in the APL literature. Variable names beginning with quad are system variables which change the environment. IO = "index origin".

Comment: Save a byte: `(4⍴2)⊤` → `2⊥⍣¯1`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>42</s> 7 [bytes](//github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁴ḶBUz0Y
```

[Try it online!](//jelly.tryitonline.net#code=4oG04bi2QlV6MFk)

Thanks to Dennis for his help. [Here](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32374772#32374772) is the first message, [here](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32384887#32384887) is the last (other discussions also occured). With his help, I apparently (almost) square-rooted the score.

Comment: Since the language is newer than question,  I can't accept it as answer. Definitely in the running for the bounty, tho!

Comment: @luserdroog That's fine. But, I thought the challenge was newer.

Comment: I know what you mean, it doesn't feel like that long ago that I posted it. But even my own inca2, at 2 years old, is too young a language.

Comment: +1 for the 42 to 7 codegolf. That's something you don't see every day (unless done on purpose).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Why should it be ever done on purpose? I'm just a Jelly newbie (I know Python 2 and 3 well), so I did it on a string way, while I "need to treat Jelly as an array-manipulating language".

Answer (score 5):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 51 bytes

[Try it online](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L2EvMDEwMS9hYWFhCi9iLzAwMTEvYmJiYgovei8wMDAwLy9vLzExMTEvem96bwp6em9v&input=)

```
/a/0101/aaaa
/b/0011/bbbb
/z/0000//o/1111/zozo
zzoo
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You beat me to it.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Feel free to improve, but I think that's the shortest possible version. :)

Comment: I'm porting this to Sprects.

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript (<strike>18 17</strike> 15 chars)

(With thanks to Howard)

```
16,zip{','-~n}%
```

I don't understand why the 10-char

```
16,zip{n}/
```

doesn't work; I suspect that a bug in the standard interpreter is resulting in unsupported types on the stack.

An alternative at 18 characters which I understand fully is:

```
4,{2\?.2,*$8@/*n}%
```

A more mathematical approach is a bit longer, at 28 chars:

```
4,{2.@??)2.4??.@/+2base(;n}/
```

A lot of that is for the base conversion and zero-padding. Without those, it drops to 19 chars,

```
4,{2.@??)2.4??\/n}/
```

with output

```
21845
13107
3855
255
```

Comment: It was asked for exact text output - why should `16,zip{n}/` work then?

Comment: On the other hand you can do `16,zip{','-~n}%`

Comment: @Howard, I think that `zip` should return an array of arrays, but it actually seems to return an array of Ruby arrays (is my best guess). Whatever the elements are, applying `` ` `` to them doesn't affect the way they print, which is unlike any of the 4 GolfScript data types. You're right that `','-` seems to turn them into normal arrays: nice trick.

Comment: Seems to output 4 extra lines of zeros here

Comment: @aditsu, [works on the online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTYsemlweycsJy1%2Bbn0l). I wonder why the difference. Ruby version, maybe?

Comment: I think the online demo is known to be buggy/old, but generally golfscript is quite quirky and it looks like you found a super-quirky feature/bug. How does that even make sense? Zipping an array of numbers converts to base 2?!

Answer (score 3):

### Postscript <del>108</del> <del>177</del> <del>126</del> <del>77</del> <del>74</del> 70

```
[43690 52428 61680 65280]
{16{dup 2 mod =only 2 idiv}repeat<>=}forall
```

Reversed the values for a simpler *mod-* off method.

### <del>151</del> <del>131</del> 119

Applying a more *APL*-ish approach. *edit:* replaced string chopping and array zipping with indexing and for-loops.

```
[[0 1 15{}for]{16 add 2 5 string cvrs}forall]4 
-1 1{0 1 15{2 index exch get 1 index 1
getinterval =only}for pop<>=}for
```

Indented:

```
[[0 1 15{}for]{16 add 2 5 string cvrs}forall]
4 -1 1{ % [] i
    0 1 15{ % [] i j
        2 index exch get % [] i [](j)
        1 index 1  % [] i [](j) i 
        getinterval  % [] i [](j)<i>
        =only  % [] i
    }for 
    pop<>= % []
}for
```

Reimplementing the functions used in the winning J answer leads to this (with a lot of [support code](https://gist.github.com/luser-dr00g/9382217)).

```
-1 16 i + #: |: |.{{==only}forall()=}forall
```

`i` here is 1-based vector described in Iverson's *Elementary Functions*, hence the `-1 ... +` to produce `0 .. 15`.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam - 16

```
4,{G,f{\m>2%}N}/
```

Equivalent java code (as explanation):

```
public class Lookup {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
                System.out.print((j >> i) % 2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ECMA6), 67

```
s=(k,n)=>n-.5?s((k<<n/2)^k,n/2)+"0".repeat(n)+k.toString(2)+"\n":""
```

To use this, call

```
s(255,8)
```

Bitshift!
And also XOR and a bit of recursion.

The first thing to notice is that if we take any line and you shift it (# of continuous 0's) / 2 left, we get a nice XOR to get the next line up.

For example,

```
0000000011111111 //line 4
0000111111110000 //shifted 4 to the left
```

XOR these bitwise give us

```
0000111100001111 //XOR'ed. This is line 3!
```

which is the next line up (line 3).
Applying the same process for line 3, shift 2 left and we get...

```
0000111100001111
0011110000111100
```

XOR'ed gives

```
0011001100110011
```

which is line 2.
Notice that the amount we shift halves each time.
Now we simply call this function recursively, with 2 arguments. The integer value of this line, and N, which is how much we need to shift. When we do recursing just pass in the shifted XOR'ed value and n/2.

```
"0".repeat(n)
```

is to pad 0's to the beginning of each line because toString takes out leading 0's.

Comment: +1 Very cool. I had not noticed that pattern before.

Comment: A couple byes can be cut off this by bit shifting n instead of dividing it, and replacing the new line with a template string: `s=(k,n)=>n?s((k<<n/2)^k,n>>1)+"0".repeat(n)+k.toString(2)+\`
\`:""`

Answer (score 2):

#### J, 21 characters

```
1":<.2|(2^i.4)%~/i.16
```

- `i.16` is a list of 0..15
- `2^i.4` is a list (1,2,4,8)
- `%~/` produces the table of divisions where the left argument forms rows but is the right argument to division
- `2|` calculates the remainder after dividing [each cell] by two
- `<.` floors that value to 0 or 1
- `1":` formats the table with one character per cell

Comment: I feel like the `floor` should not be necessary. The domain of `2|` is already 0 or 1, right?

Comment: @luserdroog [`|` operates on floats](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d230.htm). `2|3.25` is `1.25`. We don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

#### GolfScript, 19 chars

Another GolfScript approach

```
4,{2\?{&!!}+16,%n}%
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby (44)

Boring and long: Just printing the 0-padded binary representations of the numbers.

```
[21845,13107,3855,255].map{|i|puts"%016b"%i}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl (36+1)

+1 for `say`, as usual.  the double `0` is not a typo :)

```
map say((00x$_,1x$_)x(8/$_)),1,2,4,8
```

Comment: No need to add 1 for `say`. `perl -e'...'` is standard and this requires `perl -E'...'`, no increase in byte count. Anyway, I think it was decided on [meta] that `-M5.01` is free.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, 65 bytes

Not the shortest, but not the longest either:

```bash
for i in {1,2,4,8};{ eval echo \$\[\({0..15}\&$i\)/$i];}|tr -d \
```

(The last character is a space)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@WX6SQqZCZp1BtqGOkY6JjUWtdrZBalpijkJqcka8QoxITHaNRbaCnZ2haG6Omkhmjqa@SGWtdW1NSpKCbohCj8P8/AA).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ECMA6), 108

Trying a different approach here. Even though it was encouraged to use binary operators, I allowed myself to submit this solution since the challange is also [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) and I was thinking - how can I reduce the amount of code representing those values...? **Bases**.

```
['gut','a43','2z3','73'].forEach(n=>{a=parseInt(n,36).toString(2);
alert(('00000000'+a).substr(a.length-8))})
```

(Line break for convenience).

It's a shame I had to mess with padding with leading zeros, but the point of this code is simply representing the target binary result in Base 36, which are exactly those `gut, a43, 2z3, 73` values.

Note: I realize it won't be anywhere near the winning answer, but just for the sake of the idea...

Comment: I was about to do basically the same thing when I saw yours. I got it down to 92 bytes using the technique from [my answer to a similar question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39808/29750): `alert(['gut','a43','2z3',73].map(n=>(1e8+parseInt(n,36).toString(2)).slice(-16)).join('\n'))`. This approach uses newlines instead of four `alert()`s.

Answer (score 2):

## [Sprects](//dinod123.neocities.org/interpreter.html), 44 bytes

```
 aaaa
bbbb
zozo
zzoo o1111 z0000 b0011 a0101
```

Cedric's answer ported to Sprects.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
16:qYB!P
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTY6cVlCIVA&input=)

#### Explanation

```
16:    % Generate range [1 2 ... 16]
q      % Subtract 1, element-wise
YB     % Convert to binary. Gives a 16×4 char array. Each original number is a row
!      % Transpose
P      % Reverse vertically. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*Thanks to @Dennis for 1 byte off!*

```
Y4m*zW%N*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=WTRtKnpXJU4q&input=)

#### Explanation

```
Y     e# Push 2
4     e# Push 4
m*    e# Cartesian power of 2 (interpreted as [0 1]) with exponent 4
z     e# Zip
W%    e# Reverse the order of rows
N*    e# Join with newlines. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>58</s> 52 bytes

Builds the string recursively.

```
f=(n=64)=>n--?f(n)+(!n|n&15?'':`
`)+(n>>(n>>4)&1):''
```

#### How it works

This recursion is based on the fact that the pattern is made of the vertical binary representation of nibbles 0x0 to 0xF:

```
  0101010101010101 bit #0 <- Y = 0
  0011001100110011 bit #1
  0000111100001111 bit #2
  0000000011111111 bit #3 <- Y = 3
  ----------------
  0123456789ABCDEF
  ^              ^
X = 0          X = 15
```

Therefore, each position (X,Y) in this pattern can be expressed as the Y-th bit of X: `X & (1 << Y)`. We can also isolate this bit with: `(X >> Y) & 1`. Rather than keeping track of X and Y, we iterate on a single variable `n` ranging from 0 to 63. So, the formula becomes: `(n >> (n >> 4)) & 1`. It's actually easier to iterate from 63 to 0, so the string is built in reverse order. In other words, character *n-1* is appended to the left of character *n*.

As a side note, recursion doesn't bring anything here except shorter code.

Without the linebreaks, the code is 35 bytes long:

```
f=(n=64)=>n--?f(n)+(n>>(n>>4)&1):''
```

We need 17 more bytes to insert the linebreaks. This could be shortened to 14 bytes if a leading linebreak is acceptable.

#### Demo

```js
f=(n=64)=>n--?f(n)+(!n|n&15?'':`
`)+(n>>(n>>4)&1):''

console.log(f());
```

Comment: In ideone with both languages JavaScript not compile in the exapme above there is one let more.... It is good the idea of one recursive function...

Comment: What would it take to split after the 35 bytes?

Comment: @Titus - Well. At first glance, I don't have any good solution for that. Here is a (very bad) attempt: `(f=(n=64)=>n--?f(n)+(n>>(n>>4)&1):'')().match(/.{16}/g).join\`\n\` ` (63 bytes)

Comment: hmm ... and `.replace(/.{16}/g,"$0\n")` has the same length. Too bad.

Comment: `f=(n=64)=>n--?f(n)+(n>>(n>>4)&1)+(~n%16?'':"\n"):'';` with a trailing newline, which seems more reasonable

Answer (score 1):

### C <del>83</del> <del>77</del> <del>76</del> <del>74</del> 71

```
x;f(n){for(;x<4;x++,puts(""))for(n=0;n<16;)putchar(49-!(n++&(1<<x)));}
```

Pretty straightforward.

```
x;
f(n){
    for(;x<4;x++,puts(""))
        for(n=0;n<16;)
            putchar(49-!(n++&(1<<x)));
}
```

Comment: There's an easy saving of 2 by not using `?:`, and another saving of 1 by moving a `++`.

Comment: Saved 3 by changing `main` to `f`. lol

Answer (score 1):

### NARS2000 APL, 22

```
"01"[⊖1+(4⍴2)⊤(⍳16)-1]
```

Derived from marinus's APL answer, which doesn't seem to work on NARS2000.

Generate vector

```
      ⍳16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

Change to zero-based

```
      (⍳16)-1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Generate shape for encode

```
      (4⍴2)
2 2 2 2
```

Encode

```
      (4⍴2)⊤(⍳16)-1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Adjust for 1-based indexing

```
      1+(4⍴2)⊤(⍳16)-1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Reverse primary axis

```
      ⊖1+(4⍴2)⊤(⍳16)-1
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Index

```
      "01"[⊖1+(4⍴2)⊤(⍳16)-1]
0101010101010101
0011001100110011
0000111100001111
0000000011111111
```

Comment: You can set ⎕IO to 0, so that you don't have to adjust for 1-based indexing. That brings it down to 16 characters.

Comment: Yes, but then I fear it's too similar to the other APL answer and wouldn't deserve to be here at all.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 73 chars

```
i;main(){for(;i<64;)i&15||puts(""),putchar(48|1&~0xFF0F0F33335555>>i++);}
```

This is just a general solution for outputting 64 bits in four 16-bit blocks; you just need to change the number `0xFF0F0F33335555` to output an other bit sequence.

simplified & ungolfed:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if(i % 16 == 0) {
            puts("");
        }
        int bit = ~0xFF0F0F33335555 >> i;
        bit &= 1;
        putchar('0' + bit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 73

Yikes, 73 chars! I can't for the love of god get this any smaller though.

```hs
r=replicate
f n=r(div 8n)("01">>=r n)>>=id
main=mapM(putStrLn.f)[1,2,4,8]
```

The real sad part about this is that if you were to echo the output using bash, you'd only need 74 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [inca2](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca), <del>33</del> <del>27</del> 24

```
4 16#(,`2|(~16)%.2^~4){D
```

This is based on [Jan Dvorak's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12109/2381). inca2 is able to execute this as of yesterday's bugfixes. Technically invalid since the language was invented after the question, *but* invention of a language was part of my goal in posing the question. So here's some payback in gratitude to the other answers. :)

Explanation:

```
4 16#(,`2|(~16)%.2^~4){D
          (~16)               integers 0 .. 15 
                 2^~4         first 4 powers of 2: 1 2 4 8
          (~16)%.2^~4         division table
        2|                    mod 2 (and floor)
       `                      transpose
      ,                       ravel
     (               ){D      map to chars '0'..'9'
4 16#                         reshape to 4x16
```

Some of the parentheses should be unnecessary, but apparently there are some remaining issues with my interpretation of the grammar. And "ravel => map => reshape" is really clumsy: map needs to be smarter. *Edit:* bugfixes allow elimination of parens.

---

Factoring the base conversion into a separate function `N:x|y%.x^~1+[]/x.y` yields this <del>**19**</del> **16** char version.

```
4 16#(,`2N~16){D
```

---

And while I'm cheating anyway here, I've gone ahead and made this a built-in function. But, even though it's a *niladic* function (not requiring an argument), there is no support for niladic functions, and it must be supplied with a dummy argument.

## inca2, 2

```
U0
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES5) 69

`for(x="";4>x;x++){z="";for(n=0;16>n;)z+=1-!(n++&1<<x);console.log(z)}`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth 24 / 26

The shortest method was grc's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12104/15203) translated to Pyth which I felt was cheap so I did my own method:

#### Mine: 26 characters

```
 mpbjk*/8dS*d[0 1)[1 2 4 8
```

#### grc's: 24 characters

```
Fd[1 2 4 8)*/8d+*\0d*\1d
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++ 130

Converts hex to binary

```
#define B std::bitset<16>
#define C(x) cout<<x<<endl;
void main(){
B a(0xFF),b(0xF0F),c(0x3333),d(0x5555);
C(d)C(c)C(b)C(a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (Lambdabot), 47 bytes

```
unlines$reverse$transpose$replicateM 4['1','0']
```

Kinda cheaty because it uses *transpose* from Data.List and *replicateM* from Control.Monad, however both are loaded by default from Lambdabot.

Also, I'm sure there is room for improvement, just wanted to share the idea

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>53</s> 41 bytes

A translation of @grc's python answer. Shaved off 12 bytes from the original translation through use of `rep()`'s `each` and `length` arguments (and partial argument matching), and by remembering that `0:1` is equivalent to `c(0,1)`.

```
for(n in 2^(0:3))print(rep(0:1,e=n,l=16))
```

```
for(n in 2^(0:3))print(rep(c(rep(0,n),rep(1,n)),8/n))
```

You can also attempt a translation of @Gareth's J answer, something like this (34 bytes):

```
t(e1071::bincombinations(4))[4:1,]
```

However, it uses a function that's not part of base R, and outputs a matrix which is hard to format into exact printed text like in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia (39 Bytes)

Second script I've ever written in Julia, gotta admit I'm liking Julia, she's a pretty beast.

```
hcat(map(x->collect(bin(x,4)),0:15)...)
```

**Returns**

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
```

Explanation:

- `bin(x,4)` - Convert int to binary integer with padding to 4 characters.
- `collect(_)` - Split string into char array.
- `map(x->_,0:15)` - Do this for the first 16 digits in the range.
- `hcat(_...)` - Splat and horizontally concatenate into a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP , 56 Bytes

```
for(;$i<64;$i++)echo($i%16?"":"\n").($i&2**($i>>4)?1:0);
```

86 Bytes

```
for($i=1;$i<9;$i*=2)echo str_repeat(str_pad(decbin(2**$i-1),2*$i,0,0),16/(2*$i))."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

**C 70 bytes**

```
c,k=1,i;x(){putchar(48+i);i^=!(++c%k);c%16||(k*=2)+puts("");k>8||x();}
```

use recursive function... in https://ideone.com/ it compile and result:

```
0101010101010101
0011001100110011
0000111100001111
0000000011111111
```

even if in the compiler i use it does not compile...

Comment: all functions that use global variables, if they use their value 0, can be ok only one time or only if global variable are at start 0

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>76</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>67</s> <s>61</s> <s>57</s> 45 bytes

Now it´s worth it: code shorter than its output. :)

```
for(;$x<64;$x++)echo$x%16?"":"
",$x>>$x/16&1;
```

run with `-r`.

runs through rows and columns in one loop:
`$x/16` rounded is the row number,
`$x%16` the column and decimal value of the binary value we want to display:

In columns 0,16,32,48 (`$x%%16` falsy) print a linebreak.
If bit `$x/16` is set (`$x>>$x/16&1`), print `1`, else `0`.

---

add 2 bytes for trailing instead of leading linebreak:

```
for(;$x<64;$x++)echo$x>>$x/16&1,$x+1&15?"":"
";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 bytes

- -1 character thanks to Jacob

```
16Rb4zKZtr.J
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FmsMzYKSTKq8o0qK9LwgQlCZBVAaAA)

Port of Gareth's J answer.

##### Explanation

```
16Rb4zKZtr.J
16R            # Push [0, 1, ... 15]
   b           # Convert each to binary
     zK        # Pad each string with "0"s
    4          # to 4 characters
       Zt      # Transpose the resulting list
         r     # Reverse this list
          .J   # Join each inner list by ""
               # N flag joins the list by newlines
               # Implicit output
```

Comment: Can you explain why Thunno programs are counted in their character count multiplied by log256(96)? I thought it used ASCII which is one character per byte, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't really understand how but `16Rbe04zLEZtr.J` for 15 chars works. My guess is that Thunno interprets `04` as two distinct integers rather than just `4`, and `zL` can stringify an integer for its argument?

Comment: @Jacob Thunno uses the 96 printable ASCII characters as its codepage. There was a discussion about this when Fig (which also does the same thing) was released, and the conclusion was that the character count can be multiplied by `log_256(96)`.

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion! I forgot about that. Basically, the interpreter will push any leading 0s separately, and you're right in saying that `zL` stringifies it's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
GÇ¤ùT4ÃÕÔ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=R8ek%2bVQ0w9XU)

```
GÇ¤ùT4ÃÕÔ
G             :16
 Ç            :Map the range [0,G)
  ¤           :  To binary string
   ù          :  Left pad
    T         :    With 0
     4        :    To length 4
      Ã       :End map
       Õ      :Transpose
        Ô     :Reverse
              :Implicit output joined with new lines
```