# The Ackermann function

Tags: code-golf, math, recursion

The Ackermann function is notable for being the one of the simplest examples of a total, computable function that isn't primitive recursive.

We will use the definition of \$A(m,n)\$ taking in two nonnegative integers where

$$\begin{align}
A(0,n) & = n+1 \\
A(m,0) & = A(m-1,1) \\
A(m,n) & = A(m-1,A(m,n-1))
\end{align}$$

You may implement

- a named or anonymous function taking two integers as input, returning an integer, or
- a program taking two space- or newline-separated integers on STDIN, printing a result to STDOUT.

You may not use an Ackermann function or hyperexponentiation function from a library, if one exists, but you may use any other function from any other library. Regular exponentiation is allowed.

Your function must be able to find the value of \$A(m,n)\$ for \$m \le 3\$ and \$n \le 10\$ in less than a minute. It must at least *theoretically* terminate on any other inputs: given infinite stack space, a native Bigint type, and an arbitrarily long period of time, it would return the answer. *Edit:* If your language has a default recursion depth that is too restrictive, you may reconfigure that at no character cost.

The submission with the shortest number of characters wins.

Here are some values, to check your answer:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
A & n = 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
\hline
m=0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15 & 17 & 19 & 21 & 23 \\
3 & 5 & 13 & 29 & 61 & 125 & 253 & 509 & 1021 & 2045 & 4093 & 8189 \\
4 & 13 & 65533 & \text{big}
\end{array}$$

Comment: How has this not been asked before??

Comment: Tried in Python, got ~60 bytes and a lot of stack overflows. Decided not to post as anything that can only calculate `m <= 2` is not very useful :D

Comment: I think it'd be more fun to make this [tag:fastest-code]

Comment: Downvoting because there's no challenge here. The obvious answer -- just naively implementing the function exactly according to its definition -- is always going to be the best answer. So the question is just "Which language has the least number of characters in the obvious expression of Ackermann's function?" The true winner is the programming language, not the person who wrote the obvious program in it.

Comment: I agree that this challenge would be more interesting as a fastest code, currently this challenge seems to be mostly, how can I implement the ackerman function in as little characters without much consideration to speed.
Instead of how can I make use of any patterns in the ackerman function to speed it up

Comment: What if my language's recursion limit is too low to compute `A(3,8)` and above as naively as the others did? Do I have to come up with a non-recursion solution, or can I also just "assume infinite stack space" in these cases? I'm fairly certain, it would terminate within a minute.

Comment: @DavidRicherby "The obvious answer [...] is always going to be the best answer." This is not true of all languages. I feel a little dirty for only having an example in my home language, but there are multiple ways to express Ackermann and in some languages you can get savings by using that fact. This was my intention for the challenge.

Comment: @Sp3000 A problem with fastest-code is what counts as cheating. My SO answer to a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12188327/400547 used shortcuts for `m < 3` and one could add `return BigInteger.Pow(2, n + 3) - 3` for `m == 3` too. Does that count as cheating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19

```
DaGHR?atG?aGtHH1GhH
```

Defines `a`, which works as the Ackermann function. Note that this requires a higher recursion depth than the official pyth compiler allowed up until today to compute `a 3 10`, so I increased the recursion depth. This is not a change to the language, just to the compiler.

#### Test:

```
$ time pyth -c "DaGHR?atG?aGtHH1GhH           ;a 3 10"
8189

real    0m0.092s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m0.000s
```

#### Explanation:

```
DaGH                     def a(G,H):
    R                    return
    ?          G                (if G:
     atG                              (a(G-1,
        ?    H                               (if H:
         aGtH                                      a(G,H-1)
              1                               else:1)
                hH               else:H+1)
```

Essentially, it first conditions on the truth value of `G` whether to recurse or return H+1. If it is recursing, the first argument is always G-1, and it conditions on the truth value of `H` whether to use `a(G,H-1)` as the second argument, or to use `1` as the second argument.

Comment: In modern Pyth (I assume this was added after this challenge) I think you can more or less change `DaGHR` to `M` and `a` to `g`. (Did the order of arguments for `?` change?)

Comment: @Mauris Yes, you can use `M` instead, and yes, `?` argument order changed. It's now condition, true, false. It was true, condition, false.

Comment: @Lynn Fun Pyth history facts: This question actually influenced isaacg to change (at least) two things about Pyth: [the recursion limit](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/924bdbb71296efe02ba8c686a9690b7b8cd2efc4) and [the change to `M`](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/ead8a43d6d4e6050d3217acbcfc0dce0c2f73e80)!

Answer (score 26):

## Haskell, 35

```
0%n=1+n
m%n=iterate((m-1)%)1!!(n+1)
```

this defines the operator function `%`.

this works by noticing that `m%n` (where `a` is the ackerman function) for nonzero `m` is `(m-1)%` applied `n+1` times to `1`. for example, `3%2` is defined as `2%(3%1)` which is `2%(2%(3%0))`, and this is `2%(2%(2%1))`

Comment: too bad I can't use `0%n` instead of `n+1` because of precedence

Comment: [What am I doing wrong?](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1HBwFbDUFuTK1Eh11YjsyS1KLEkVSNRJVfXUNNQUVHzf25iZp6CrUJBaUlwSZGCikJxRn45kEpUMDRQMP4PAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: wow, this has been wrong for so long, and nobody, including myself, noticed? good work. so it seems I mistakenly copied the first version of the answer, which was faulty, maybe by mistake or because I thought it worked.

Answer (score 16):

## [Binary lambda calculus](https://tromp.github.io/cl/cl.html), 54 bits = 6.75 bytes

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 1607 2d88 072f 68                        ..-../h
```

Binary:

```
000101100000011100101101100010000000011100101111011010
```

This is λ*m*. *m* (λ*g*. λ*n*. *g* (*n* *g* 1)) (λ*n*. λ*f*. λ*x*. *f* (*n* *f* *x*)), where all numbers are represented as [Church numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals).

Answer (score 12):

### GolfScript (30)

```
{1$1>{1\){1$(\A}*\;}{+)}if}:A;
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ezEkMT57MVwpezEkKFxBfSpcO317Kyl9aWZ9OkE7CgozIDEwIEE%3D)

Without the `1>` (which special-cases `A(1, n)`) it takes 9 minutes to compute `A(3, 10)` on the computer I've tested it on. With that special case it's fast enough that the online demo takes less than 10 seconds.

Note that this *isn't* a naïve translation of the definition. The recursion depth is bounded by `m`.

#### Dissection

```
{             # Function boilerplate
  1$          # Get a copy of m: stack holds m n m
  1>{         # (Optimisation): if m is greater than 1
    1         #   Take this as the value of A(m, -1)
    \){       #   Repeat n+1 times:
              #     Stack: m A(m, i-1)
      1$(\    #     Stack: m m-1 A(m, i-1)
      A       #     Stack: m A(m, i)
    }*
    \;        #   Lose that unwanted copy of m
  }{          # Else
    +)        #   A(m in {0, 1}, n) = m + n + 1
  }if
}:A;          # Function boilerplate
```

Comment: In CJam, you wouldn't need `1>`. After removal (and changing `if` to `?`), computing `3 10 A` takes 110 seconds with the online interpreter and six seconds with the Java interpreter.

Answer (score 7):

## J - 26 char

```
($:^:(<:@[`]`1:)^:(0<[)>:)
```

There is an alternate, more functional definition of Ackermann:

```
Ack 0 n = n+1
Ack m n = Iter (Ack (m-1)) n
Iter f 0 = f 1
Iter f n = f (Iter f (n-1))
```

It so happens that `Iter` is very easy to write in J, because J has a way of passing in the `m-1` to `Ack` and also to define the initial value of `Iter` to be 1. Explained by explosion:

```
(                      >:)  NB. increment n
                ^:(0<[)     NB. if m=0, do nothing to n+1; else:
   ^:                       NB. iterate...
($:                      )  NB.   self ($: is recursion)
     (<:@[     )            NB.   with left arg m-1
          `]                NB.   n+1 times
            `1:             NB.   starting on 1
```

This relies on what J calls the gerund form of `^:`—basically a way to have more control over all the bounds in a tacit (point-free) fashion.

At the REPL:

```
   3 ($:^:(<:@[`]`1:)^:(0<[)>:) 3
61
   ack =: ($:^:(<:@[`]`1:)^:(0<[)>:)
   (i.4) ack"0 table (i.11)
+-----+------------------------------------------+
|ack"0|0  1  2  3   4   5   6    7    8    9   10|
+-----+------------------------------------------+
|0    |1  2  3  4   5   6   7    8    9   10   11|
|1    |2  3  4  5   6   7   8    9   10   11   12|
|2    |3  5  7  9  11  13  15   17   19   21   23|
|3    |5 13 29 61 125 253 509 1021 2045 4093 8189|
+-----+------------------------------------------+
   6!:2 '3 ($:^:(<:@[`]`1:)^:(0<[)>:) 10'  NB. snugly fits in a minute
58.5831
```

We need to define `ack` by name to be able to put it in a table, because `$:` is a horrible, ugly beast and lashes out at anyone who attempts to understand it. It is self-reference, where self is defined as the largest verb phrase containing it. `table` is an adverb and so would love to become part of the verb phrase if you give it the chance, so you have to trap `$:` in a named definition to use it.

---

#### Edit: 24 char?

Years later, I found a solution which is two characters shorter.

```
(0&<~(<:@#~$:/@,1:^:)>:)
```

It's a lot slower, though: `3 ack 8` takes over a minute on my machine. This is because (1) I use a fold `/` instead of iteration, so J probably has to remember more things than usual, and (2) while `0&<~` performs the same calculation as `(0<[)`, it actually gets executed `n+1` times *before taking the recursive step* when invoking `m ack n`—`0&<` happens to be idempotent, so it doesn't ruin the calculation, but `n` gets big fast and `ack` is highly recursive.

I am doubtful that a more powerful machine could push the new code under a minute, because this is a computer where the old code can find `3 ack 10` in less than 15 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript, ES6, <s>41</s> 34 bytes

```
f=(m,n)=>m?f(m-1,!n||f(m,n-1)):n+1
```

Run this in a latest Firefox Console and it will create a function called `f` which you can call with different values of `m` and `n` like

```
f(3,2) // returns 29
```

OR

try the code below in a latest Firefox

```js
f=(m,n)=>m?f(m-1,!n||f(m,n-1)):n+1

B.onclick=_=>alert(f(+M.value, +N.value))
```

```css
#M,#N{max-width:15px;border: 1px solid;border-width:0 0 1px 0}
```

```html
<div>f(<input id=M />,<input id=N />)</div><br><button id=B>Evaluate</button>
```

Comment: Testing this with 0,1 in Chrome gives no result.

Comment: Pl read, this only works in latest Firefox due to ES6

Comment: Wow... we have 4 practically identical JS solutions, all at 34 bytes. I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2.7.8 - <s>80, 54, 48, 46</s> 45

```
A=lambda m,n:m and A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))or-~n
```

(Credits to xnor!)

More readable, but with 1 more character:

```
A=lambda m,n:n+(m<1or A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))-n)
```

Not that I had to set `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)` in order to get a result for `A(3,10)`. Further golfing using logical indexing did not work due to the dramatically growing recursion depth.

Comment: I get a syntax error on the `1else`. The start letter `e` causes trouble for the parser because numbers can be written like `1e3`.

Comment: Saved a few chars switching to `and/or`: `A=lambda m,n:m and A(m-1,n<1or A(m,n-1))or-~n`

Comment: @xnor: Thanks for the tip! See [this discussion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39791/30372) for the parsing issue issue. Python 2.7.8 accepts `1else`, most other versions don't.

Comment: Thanks for pointer about `1else`; it lets me squeeze out a char [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38531/20260) and probably other places. But darn is it version-specific! Python 2.7.4 doesn't allow it. Are you using an online version with 2.7.8 or would I have to download it?

Comment: @xnor: It's an offline installation. http://ideone.com/, e.g., fails to parse `1else` as well.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman See my answer for how to use `D` and how to use Pyth's ternary.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman The two more changes needed to save 2 more characters are: 1. change `<Z1` to `!Z` - we just want to test whether `Z` is 0, so using a not saves a character. 2. Use `?` instead of `|&`, and move the conditional, `Y` in this case, in between the true case and the false case (just before `hZ`).

Answer (score 5):

## C - 41 bytes

Nothing to it--the small limits mean that all the required values can be calculated in less than 1 second by naively following the function definition.

```
A(m,n){return!m?n+1:A(m-1,n?A(m,n-1):1);}


int main()
{
    int m,n;
    for(m = 0; m <= 3; m++)
    for(n = 0; n <= 10; n++)
    printf("%d %d %d\n", m,n,A(m,n));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6 (34)

```js
a=(m,n)=>m?a(m-1,n?a(m,n-1):1):n+1
```

#### Implementation:

```js
a=(m,n)=>m?a(m-1,n?a(m,n-1):1):n+1
```

```css
td[colspan="2"] input{width: 100%;}
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>m=</td><td><input id="m" type="number" value="0" /></td></tr><tr><td>n=</td><td><input id="n" type="number" value="0" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Calculate!" onclick="document.getElementById('out').value=a(document.getElementById('m').value, document.getElementById('n').value)" /></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><input id="out" disabled="disabled" type="text" /></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 5):

## Coq, 40

```
nat_rec _ S(fun _ b n=>nat_iter(S n)b 1)
```

This is a function of type `nat -> nat -> nat`.  Since Coq only allows the construction of total functions, it also serves as a formal proof that the Ackermann recurrence is well-founded.

Demo:

```
Welcome to Coq 8.4pl6 (November 2015)

Coq < Compute nat_rec _ S(fun _ b n=>nat_iter(S n)b 1) 3 10.
     = 8189
     : nat
```

Note: Coq 8.5, released after this challenge, renamed `nat_iter` to `Nat.iter`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6) - 34

```js
A=(m,n)=>m?A(m-1,!n||A(m,n-1)):n+1
```

And a test:

```js
> A=(m,n)=>m?A(m-1,!n||A(m,n-1)):n+1;s=new Date().getTime();console.log(A(3,10),(new Date().getTime() - s)/1000)
8189 16.441
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
+‘ð;x’ß@ƒ1ðỊ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//K@KAmMOwO3jigJnDn0DGkjHDsOG7ij//M8W7w6fDvjEwxbvCpFpH/w)

Again uses [proud haskeller's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40172/78410): `A(m+1,n)` is `A(m,?)` applied `n+1` times to 1.

The base case should've been simply `A(0,n) = n+1`, but unfortunately it (the code at the bottom) times out badly, so I had to use `A(m,n) = m+n+1 if m <= 1` instead.

#### How it works

```
+‘ð;x’ß@ƒ1ðỊ?    Dyadic link. Left = m, Right = n
AAðBBBBBBBðC?    If C, do A; otherwise, do B
           Ị     If m <= 1...
+‘               Return m+n+1
   ;x’ß@ƒ1       Otherwise do this:
   ;x            Concatenate m to n copies of m (which gives n+1 copies of m)
     ’           Decrement each number (n+1 copies of m-1)
        ƒ1       Reduce with seed 1...
      ß@         This function, args swapped (since new m is on the right side)
```

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes, times out on A(3,9)

```
;x’ß@ƒ1ð‘}ḷ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//O3jigJnDn0DGkjHDsOKAmH3huLc//zPFu8Onw741xbvCpFpH/w)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 46 bytes

```
0~a~n_:=n+1
m_~a~n_:=a[m-1,If[n<1,1,a[m,n-1]]]
```

Takes pretty much exactly a minute for `a[3,10]`. Note that Mathematica's default recursion limit is too small for `a[3,8]` and beyond (at least on my machine), but that can be fixed by configuring

```
$RecursionLimit = Infinity
```

Comment: Wow, so are you saying that JS is more than 25 times faster than Mathematica ?

Comment: @Optimizer At least when it comes to recursion... I guess part if it is that it has to figure out each time which definition to use, and `If` being a function is even slower.

Comment: With memoization, it takes 0.07 seconds.  I.e. `m_~a~n_:=m~a~n=`...

Comment: @MarkAdler That's a really nice way to do memoisation in Mathematica!

Comment: You can save a byte with an immediate assignment on the first line: `0~a~n_=n+1`

Comment: Alternatively, `a@0=#+1&;a@m_:=a[m-1]@If[#<1,1,a[m][#-1]]&` would be 42 bytes but needs to be called as `a[m][n]`

Comment: I know this answer is several years old, but if any of the users in this thread are still active on this site, could you please explain how m_~a~n:=m~a~n=... achieves memoization in Mathematica? What is the ... supposed to be in this function definition?

Comment: @dirvine Just the regular value of the function, so `a[m-1,If[n<1,1,a[m,n-1]]]` in this particular example. How it works is that everything to the right of `:=` is evaluated when the function is called. That is the assignment `m~a~n=...` which then gets stored as a special case that takes precedence over the more general definition next time the function is called with these values.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>48</s> 44 chars (36 for the list)

While not as short as the other Haskell solution, this one is notable because it expresses the Ackermann function as an infinite list, which I think is kinda neat.  The result is an infinite list (of infinite lists) such that at position *[m,n]* it holds the value *A(m,n)*.

The infinite list itself:

```hs
iterate(tail.(`iterate`1).(!!))[1..]
```

As a function (to comply with the specification):

```hs
i=iterate;m%n=i(tail.(`i`1).(!!))[1..]!!m!!n
```

---

The formulation was derived by observing that the general/common case for the Ackermann function is to use the value to the left as an index in the row above.  The base case for this recursion (i.e. the leftmost column of a row, i.e. *A(m,0)*) is to use the second left-most value in the row above.  The base case for *that* recursion is the *A(0,n) = n+1* case, i.e. the first row is `[1..]`.

Thus, we get

```hs
let a0 = [1..]
let a1 = tail $ iterate (a0 !!) 1  -- 'tail' because iterate starts by applying
let a2 = tail $ iterate (a1 !!) 1  -- the function 0 times
-- etc
```

Then we simply add another level of iteration based on that pattern, and do some [pointless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) juggling.

Comment: You could alias `iterate` to a single letter name i.e. `i=iterate;ack=i ... `

Comment: @proudhaskeller oh yeah, didn't think about that. Thanks! Borrowing your operator-name use as well.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>34</s> <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```julia
m\n=m>0?~-m\(n<1||m\~-n):n+1
```

This is a named anonymous function. It is a straightforward implementation of the recursive definition, abusing Julia's ability to [redefine operators](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/81028).

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=bVxuPW0-MD9-LW1cKG48MXx8bVx-LW4pOm4rMQoKcHJpbnQoM1wxMCk&input=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>58</s> 49 bytes

```python
a=lambda m,n:m and a(m-1,n and a(m,n-1)or 1)or-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRSFRI1fXUCcPxtbJ0zXUzC9SABG6dXn/C4oy80o0EjWMdRTMNDX/AwA)

I didn't see a Python 3 answer (there was a Python 2), so I decided to fix that and put my own answer in here. (-(43+21) thanks to caird, -9 thanks to HN)

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFRI1cnT9OKSyEzTSHXxtCqKLWktChPIU/bECyUhxACqtQ11DHU5FJAEQAboGuoqfm/oCgzr0QjUcNYR8EMyAUA)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRSMPRCokauTqGuoASZ08XUNNzfwiqAiYrVuX97@gKDOvRCNRw1hHwUxT8z8A)

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2JzE3KSVRIVcnzypXITEvRSFRI1fXUCcPxtbJ0zXUzC9SABG6dXn/C4oy80o0EjWMdRTMNDX/AwA)

Comment: I was going to mention that `n<1or` would save even more bytes but then it becomes identical to the aforementioned Python 2 answer...

Answer (score 2):

## Racket 67

```
(define(a m n)(if(= m 0)(+ n 1)(a(- m 1)(if(= n 0)1(a m(- n 1))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript with lambdas, 34

```
A=(m,n)=>m?A(m-1,n?A(m,n-1):1):n+1
```

A tipical answer, can't make anything shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tiny Lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/62886/2338), 70  (out of competition)

This runs out of competition, as the language is newer than the question, and it also doesn't succeed to run the `(A 3 10)` as required in the question, due to a stack overflow.

`(d A(q((m n)(i m(i n(A(s m 1)(A m(s n 1)))(A(s m 1)1))(s n(s 0 1))))))`

This defines a function `A` which calculates the Ackermann function.
Formatted:

```
(d A
   (q( (m n)
       (i m
          (i n
             (A (s m 1)
                (A m
                   (s n 1)
                 )
              ) 
             (A (s m 1)
                1
              )
           )
          (s n
             (s 0 1)
           )
        )
    ) )
 )
```

We are using all builtin macros (`d` (define) and `q` (quote) and `i` (if)) and one builtin function (`s` – subtract) here.

`i` executes its true part when the condition is a number > 0 (and otherwise the false part), so we don't have to do an explicit comparison here.

`s` is the only arithmetic operation available, we use it for the `n-1`/`m-1`, as well as as `(s n (s 0 1))` for `n+1`.

Tiny lisp is using tail recursion optimization, but this only helps for the outer `A` call in the result, not for the `A(m, n-1)` call which is used for the parameters.

With [my tiny lisp implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63352/2338) in Ceylon on the JVM, it works up to `(A 3 5) = 253`, but it seems to break down when trying to calculate `(A 2 125)` directly (which should give the same result). If calculating that after `(A 3 4) = 125`, the JVM seems to got to optimize the functions enough to inline some intermediate function calls in my interpreter, allowing more recursion depth. Strange.

The [reference implementation](https://gist.github.com/dloscutoff/254267bce8cb09f009ad) gets up to `(A 3 5) = 253` and also `(A 2 163) = 329`, but doesn't succeed `(A 2 164)`, and therefore even less `(A 3 6) = (A 2 253)`.

Comment: this might  be competitive save for the whitespace and parenthesis ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 90 bytes

```
>>>>+>,>,<<[>[>[-[->>>+<<<]<[->+>>+<<<]>-[-<+>]>+>>>>>]<[->+>>]]<[>>+[-<<<+>>>]<<-]<<<]>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=Pj4-Pis-LD4sPDwKWwogID4KICBbCiAgICA-CiAgICBbCiAgICAgIC1bLT4-Pis8PDxdCiAgICAgIDxbLT4rPj4rPDw8XQogICAgICA-LVstPCs-XT4rPj4-Pj4KICAgIF0KICAgIDwKICAgIFsKICAgICAgLT4rPj4KICAgIF0KICBdCiAgPAogIFsKICAgID4-K1stPDw8Kz4-Pl08PC0KICBdCiAgPDw8Cl0KPj4uCg$$)

Assumes an implementation with arbitrary sized cell size, with IO as numbers. -6 bytes if you don't mind using negative cells.

Finishes in about 30 seconds for 3,8 in the linked interpreter, provided you tick the correct settings. Type inputted numbers prepended with `\`s, e.g. `3,9` is `\3\9`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ral](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ral), <s>81</s> 61 bytes

```
,,/:11+-111:++:+:++:+:+?/0=:1/-/1/10*-0*1:+?+0=11:+?1++/1:+?.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFBb4MgGL3zK750B1FQIb2xMbNjT22W3YxZqGJKopZo221Z9tsdtDbay8fHe@97PMD@nA7Hbj0@wRu8qwZMd9K97bWrUB97@Nhs0UY2qt1XSjgSm86eTzgM0XZC4SJs75lLiCpdQ3/ucBkKBCU1dKCtzMurU@m8famvXcA4iUUaSZpkn0FBGc0L@vuHwM62Q6Ks1V3lnWF3DzEk9mhx6HwG0M2ggSH4OphGg3lp9HQ2GFpJQzgtc1P4bQ3V7dRAWOzTVu4KN1zKgHh0h0Oyw0s4nuD4ERaBUNJBzxarW5m51HF071m6UOwXimiebnNVOFT5l2mnyyyU8q70Ot/MFPXJNg@pkkBs8WPQLPBPAWqa9bDrXpkwslXfmFGXHPn/Wq1WI6Wp4O5TOOeCEEGmkqVMCp7GKU85i2IWOTYjTHpVxglJ/ZqMziEc14izfw)

**Commented**

```
Code                     Stack after        Description
,,                       0, m, n              Input m and n
                                            Loop:
/:11+-111:++:+:++:+:+?   r, n, m              Jump to SmallM if m < 2
/0=:1/-/1/10*-           r, m-1, 1, m, n-1    Perform [m, n] => [m-1, 1, m, n-1]
0*1:+?                   r, m-1, 1, m, n-1    Jump to Loop if n>0
+0=                      r, m-1, 1            Remove the last two elements
11:+?                    r, m-1, 1            Jump to Loop
                                            SmallM:
1++                      n+m+1, r             Perform [m, n] => [n+m+1]
/1:+?                    n+m+1                Jump to Loop if r>0
.                                             Print n+m+1
```

**Explanation**

Because there are no built in function calls (or recursion) in Ral, we need to simulate the stack frame. One way to do that is as follows:

1. Start with the stack [m, n]
2. Repeatedly apply the following rules, until a single element remains:

   - [..., 0, n] => [..., n+1]
   - [..., m, 0] => [..., m-1, 1]
   - [..., m, n] => [..., m-1, m, n-1]
3. Print the remaining element

However, since there is no way to know the current length of the stack in Ral, an additional flag is stored to test if the recursion should continue, resulting in the following rules:

- [..., 0, 0, n] => Print n+1 and exit
- [..., 1, 0, n] => [..., n+1]
- [..., m, 0] => [..., m-1, 1]
- [..., m, n] => [..., m-1, 1, m, n-1]

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 16 bytes

```
{x/[;1]1+}/[;1+]
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qu0I+2Now11K4F0dqxXFxp0Qax6oqGhkCGIYxhBGMYgxkAj2QNVg==)

Same structure as my K answer for [fast growing hierarchy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264876/78410), and happens to be the same length too. Can compute f(0..3)(0..10) in a couple seconds.

Again uses "`A(m+1,n)` is `A(m,?)` applied `n+1` times to 1."

```
{x/[;1]1+}/[;1+]    input: m, returns function that takes n
{        }/[;1+]    iterate m times on the function 1+ (increment):
       1+             create a function that increments n and then
 x/[;1]               run `x/[n+1;1]` == `(n+1)x/1`
                      == iterate function x n+1 times to 1
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL, 31

```
{⍺=0:⍵+1⋄⍵=0:1∇⍨⍺-1⋄(⍺-1)∇⍺∇⍵-1}
```

Pretty straightforward. Uses the ⍨ character once to save one byte by reversing arguments. Takes m as the left argument and n as the right argument.

[TryAPL.org](http://tryapl.org/)

Answer (score 1):

### R - <s>54</s> 52

I've used this as an excuse to try and get my head around R, so this is probably really badly done:)

```
a=function(m,n)"if"(m,a(m-1,"if"(n,a(m,n-1),1)),n+1)
```

Example run

```
> a(3,8)
[1] 2045
```

I get a stack overflow for anything beyond that

### T-SQL- 222

I thought I would try to get T-SQL to do it as well.  Used a different method because recursion isn't that nice in SQL.  Anything over 4,2 bombs it.

```
DECLARE @m INT=4,@n INT=1;WITH R AS(SELECT 2 C, 1 X UNION ALL   SELECT POWER(2,C),X+1FROM R)SELECT IIF(@m=0,@n+1,IIF(@m=1,@n+2,IIF(@m=2,2*@n+3,IIF(@m=3,POWER(2,@n+3)-3,IIF(@m=4,(SELECT TOP(1)C FROM R WHERE x= @n+3)-3,-1)))))
```

Comment: for your R submisson, looks like you don't need the `{}` although there's no helping the stack overflow limit, since R doesn't have TCO...

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks ... in my defense, I was new to it then :)

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <s>260</s> <s>243</s> <s>240</s> 122 bytes

I didn't see that the question allowed anon funcs.

far from competitive but i'm learning this language and i wanted to test it out.

```
func (m,n int)int{r:=0
switch{case m==0&&n!=0:r=n+1
case m!=0&&n==0:r=a(m-1,1)
case m!=0&&n!=0:r=a(m-1,a(m,n-1))}
return r}
```

use it like `go run ack.go` and then supply two numbers, `m` and `n`. if m>4 or n>30, execution time may be in excess of half a minute.

for `m=3 n=11`:

```
$ time go run ack
16381
real    0m1.434s
user    0m1.432s
sys     0m0.004s
```

*edit*: saved total 17 bytes by switching to `switch` over `if/else` and dot-imports

Comment: You can do even better! `switch 0 {case m:r=n+1 case n:r=a(m-1,1) default:r=a(m-1,a(m,n-1))}` Go's `switch` statement is so beautifully flexible!

Comment: @EMBLEM Thanks, it's been so long since I've written a line of Go, but I'm glad to see there are other Go-golfers about :D

Answer (score 1):

### Ceylon, <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 85

```ceylon
alias I=>Integer;I a(I m,I n)=>m<1then n+1else(n<1then a(m-1,1)else a(m-1,a(m,n-1)));
```

This is a straightforward implementation. Formatted:

```ceylon
alias I => Integer;
I a(I m, I n) =>
        m < 1
        then n + 1
        else (n < 1
            then a(m - 1, 1)
            else a(m - 1, a(m, n - 1)));
```

The alias saves just one byte, without it (with writing `Integer` instead of `I`) we would get to 86 bytes. Another two bytes can be saved by replacing `== 0` by `< 1` twice.

With the default settings of `ceylon run`, it will work up to `A(3,12) = 32765` (and `A(4,0) = 13`), but `A(3,13)` (and therefore also `A(4,1)`) will throw a stack overflow error. (`A(3,12)` takes about 5 seconds, `A(3,11)` about 3 on my computer.)

Using `ceylon run-js` (i.e. running the result of compiling to JavaScript on node.js) is a lot slower (needs 1 min 19 s for `A(3,10)`), and breaks already for `A(3, 11)` with a »Maximum call stack size exceeded« (using default settings) after running for 1 min 30 s.

---

### Ceylon without recursion, 228

As a bonus, here is a non-recursive version (longer, of course, but immune to stack overflows – might get an out-of-memory error at some point).

```ceylon
import ceylon.collection{A=ArrayList}Integer a(Integer[2]r){value s=A{*r};value p=s.addAll;while(true){if(exists m=s.pop()){if(exists n=s.pop()){if(n<1){p([m+1]);}else if(m<1){p([n-1,1]);}else{p([n-1,n,m-1]);}}else{return m;}}}}
```

Formatted:

```ceylon
import ceylon.collection {
    A=ArrayList
}

Integer a(Integer[2] r) {
    value s = A { *r };
    value p = s.addAll;
    while (true) {
        if (exists m = s.pop()) {
            if (exists n = s.pop()) {
                if (n < 1) {
                    p([m + 1]);
                } else if (m < 1) {
                    p([n - 1, 1]);
                } else {
                    p([n - 1, n, m - 1]);
                }
            } else {
                // stack is empty
                return m;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is quite slower on my computer than the recursive version: `A(3,11)` takes 9.5 seconds, `A(3,12)` takes 34 seconds, `A(3,13)` takes 2:08 minutes, `A(3,14)` takes 8:25 minutes. (I originally had a version using lazy iterables instead of the tuples I now have, which was even much slower, with the same size).

A bit faster (21 seconds for `A(3,12)`) (but also one byte longer) is a version using `s.push` instead of `s.addAll`, but that needed to be called several times to add multiple numbers, as it takes just a single Integer each. Using a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList is a lot slower.

Answer (score 1):

## [UGL](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
iiRuldr%l%lR$d%rd:u%d:%+uRu:ro
```

Input separated by newlines.

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aWlSdWxkciVsJWxSJGQlcmQ6dSVkOiUrdVJ1OnJv&input=Mgo1)

(It has been implemented as a standard example in the interpreter.)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 15 bytes

```
M?GgtG?HgGtH1hH
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%3FGgtG%3FHgGtH1hHg3T&debug=0) (sample usage of the function `g3T` added, which means `g(3,10)`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 67 bytes

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::A m\ n {expr {$m?A($m-1,$n?A($m,$n-1):1):$n+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BaoQwEIbP@hQ/kkOXum2kp4YNxXfYm@tB0mwbMGNIIhQkz26jazsMzMB888/8UY2roai9g9dq9sFMNBprIpaEd8756vykENUohB3i930mJUQLewNh0T/OY2H2o31i9tzUjPYu13NzEjkZPTcprfcpY0FHWPC0LVzkW66GlIfNTVn8E/Qg6CIb/ofQjhTb@IpuP9qF6A19wQ4OS2WN8lPQaqLPAKc9THY0xOylyj4Sumisfui3h8Dx56lPff/a8D1e@hsOlXzOzTGgsjJzIMmoRitZW2PTkuxalUUq0/oL)

---

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 77 bytes

```
proc A m\ n {expr {$m?[A [expr $m-1] [expr {$n?[A $m [expr $n-1]]:1}]]:$n+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BasMwEETP9lcMRre6jUxPLRHF/5Cb40NQ1SLIroWkQMHo252141QHacW8nd3J9rp4zi4GRGdvMfmJr558xlzwobVeQpwsetAZjNn9hYhZ0dfQY9g@il67ca9nxaug6KmxaONnV@RS/NKVsvxMgiWXQdBldTqad3k92wiSoq7@CX4QfDSdfiK8IdUqn/YhQ8rR8y/oEjA35G2ckrMTfycEF@El2yVLqkYSFQzZk3v4S4JtV8WjLHjo9HbexjP2fhkUbjmhIaOoBRvFLXqj@hari1Gnpq5KXZY7)

In the online compiler it fails to run due to time-out, but in a local Tcl interpreter it runs well. I profiled of each root call to `A` function, to see how much time the calculation took for each pair `{m,n}` subject to be tested:

```
m=0, n=0, A=1, time=3.5e-5 seconds
m=0, n=1, A=2, time=2e-6 seconds
m=0, n=2, A=3, time=8e-6 seconds
m=0, n=3, A=4, time=1e-6 seconds
m=0, n=4, A=5, time=2e-6 seconds
m=0, n=5, A=6, time=1e-6 seconds
m=0, n=6, A=7, time=1e-6 seconds
m=0, n=7, A=8, time=1e-6 seconds
m=0, n=8, A=9, time=1e-6 seconds
m=0, n=9, A=10, time=0.0 seconds
m=0, n=10, A=11, time=1e-6 seconds
m=1, n=0, A=2, time=4e-6 seconds
m=1, n=1, A=3, time=6e-6 seconds
m=1, n=2, A=4, time=1e-5 seconds
m=1, n=3, A=5, time=1.2e-5 seconds
m=1, n=4, A=6, time=1.5e-5 seconds
m=1, n=5, A=7, time=2e-5 seconds
m=1, n=6, A=8, time=2e-5 seconds
m=1, n=7, A=9, time=2.6e-5 seconds
m=1, n=8, A=10, time=3e-5 seconds
m=1, n=9, A=11, time=3e-5 seconds
m=1, n=10, A=12, time=3.3e-5 seconds
m=2, n=0, A=3, time=8e-6 seconds
m=2, n=1, A=5, time=2.2e-5 seconds
m=2, n=2, A=7, time=3.9e-5 seconds
m=2, n=3, A=9, time=6.3e-5 seconds
m=2, n=4, A=11, time=9.1e-5 seconds
m=2, n=5, A=13, time=0.000124 seconds
m=2, n=6, A=15, time=0.000163 seconds
m=2, n=7, A=17, time=0.000213 seconds
m=2, n=8, A=19, time=0.000262 seconds
m=2, n=9, A=21, time=0.000316 seconds
m=2, n=10, A=23, time=0.000377 seconds
m=3, n=0, A=5, time=2.2e-5 seconds
m=3, n=1, A=13, time=0.000145 seconds
m=3, n=2, A=29, time=0.000745 seconds
m=3, n=3, A=61, time=0.003345 seconds
m=3, n=4, A=125, time=0.015048 seconds
m=3, n=5, A=253, time=0.059836 seconds
m=3, n=6, A=509, time=0.241431 seconds
m=3, n=7, A=1021, time=0.971836 seconds
m=3, n=8, A=2045, time=3.908884 seconds
m=3, n=9, A=4093, time=15.926341 seconds
m=3, n=10, A=8189, time=63.734713 seconds
```

It fails for the last pair `{m,n}={3,10}`, as it takes a very little more than one minute.

For higher values of `m`, it will be needed to increase the `recursionlimit` value.

---

I coult get it shorter to 65 bytes, but it will not meet the question's requirement "Your function must be able to find the value of A(m,n) for m ≤ 3 and n ≤ 10 in less than a minute.". Without the `{}` it will timeout on TIO and not do the demo of the last two entries.

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 65 bytes

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::A m\ n {expr $m?A($m-1,$n?A($m,$n-1):1):$n+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/BasMwEETP8VcMRoeGOq1MTzURxf@Qm@ODUZVW4F0LSYaC0be7iuN2WdiFfczsRD2ulqPxDt7o2Qc78WjJRiwJ71LK1flJI@qxaWiI37eZddO0oCsYi/lxHoI@2idBp7oSvG15nupjk1vwc53W2@SxBBNBkAmLoLN6y9Oy9qC8FId/gh8En1Ut/xDekMP9fEG3WXYhestfoMFhKclqPwWjJ/4McMbD5jxDzEnKnCKhi5bMQ7/dBfY3j33q@9dabvXSX7GrZDs3x4CSVObASnCFVom2wl1LiUtZHFKR1l8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

```c
A(m,n){m=m?A(m-1,n?A(m,n-1):1):n+1;}
```

Naive strategy with a little bit of optimization.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsIwDIbvfYowEVrWisWbWx2@hxdpnRZsOub0MvbsNa0g@wnJnz/fIVbdrU3pzINEMQcTOrJKS@xKpLQ4UmGtmyVtPNrn292gfU3Ox93jxJjHCcLVI/9E7wSbGZD6OPJyAAP7hkZr4ECzrkW5rxn8MZgZnc0ayhpGwnpeBbN1ErD0/BugIH/BSkJe/qFo2JK@)

Answer (score 1):

## [Verilog (Icarus Verilog)](http://iverilog.icarus.com/), 81 bytes

Based on the [C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201372/62493). Verilog is not really intended for this kind of thing - Yosys crashes on this - but it's possible with Icarus.

```
function automatic[15:0]a;input[15:0]m,n;a=(m==0)?n+1:(n==0)?a(m-1,1):a(m-1,a(m,n-1));endfunction
```

Testbench:

```
module test();

function automatic[31:0]a;input[31:0]m,n;a=m?a(m-1,n?a(m,n-1):1):n+1;endfunction

initial begin
    $display("%d", a(3,10));
end

endmodule
```

Icarus is really not intended for this kind of constant abuse, though:

```
$ time ./a.out
 8189

real    0m55.422s
user    0m55.375s
sys     0m0.063s
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 47 bytes

```
a 0 n=n+1
a m 0=a(m-1)1
a m n=a(m-1)(a m (n-1))
```

(Run using `ghci <filename>`)
Almost directly copies from the problem definition (thank you pattern matching!).

Comment: You may want to include a [TIO link](https://tio.run) so everyone can test your submission?

Comment: I think `a(m-1)(a m (n-1))` can be `a(m-1).a m$n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

```apl
{0=⍺:1+⍵⋄1∇⍣(⍵+1)⍨⍺-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9rA9lHvLitD7Ue9Wx91txg@6mh/1LtYA8jTNtR81LsCKKlrWPs/7VHbhEe9fY/6pnr6P@pqPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/N1RIUzDhMgaShgYA)

A port of [proud haskeller's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40172/78410). Uses the fact that `Ack(m,n)` is equal to `Ack(m-1,?)` applied `n+1` times to `1`.

#### How it works

```apl
{0=⍺:1+⍵⋄1∇⍣(⍵+1)⍨⍺-1}
{                    }  ⍝ ⍺←m, ⍵←n
 0=⍺:1+⍵⋄               ⍝ If m = 0, return 1 + n
          ∇      ⍨⍺-1   ⍝ Apply (m-1)∇ (∇ is recursive call)
           ⍣(⍵+1)       ⍝ n+1 times
         1              ⍝ to the initial value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 53 bytes

Yet another recursion solution.

```
a :=method(m,n,if(m<1,n+1,a(m-1,if(n<1,1,a(m,n-1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//z9Rwco2N7UkIz9FI1cnTyczTSPXxlAnT9tQJ1EjV9cQJJAHFABzdfJ0DTVB4H@ihrGOiaZCQVFmXklO3n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
’çç’}¥ɗ’ç1Ɗṛ?‘}ḷ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zDyw8vB1K1h5aenA7mGh7rerhztv2jhhm1D3dst////7/xfxMA)

Requires a higher recursion limit for \$A(3, 10)\$ than the Jelly interpreter has, but finishes within 1 minute when I adjust the limit locally

Full program, due to some bugs with `ß`.

### How it works

```
’çç’}¥ɗ’ç1Ɗṛ?‘}ḷ? - Main link A(m, n). Takes m on the left and n on the right
                ? - If:
               ḷ  -   Condition: m is non-zero
                  -   Then:
            ?     -     If:
           ṛ      -       Condition: n in non-zero
      ɗ           -       Then:
’                 -         m-1
     ¥            -         Group the previous 2 links into a dyad f(m, n):
   ’}             -           n-1
  ç               -           A(m, n-1)
 ç                -         A(m-1, A(m, n-1)
          Ɗ       -       Else:
       ’          -         m-1
        ç1        -         A(m-1, 1)
              }   -   Else:
             ‘    -     n+1
```

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to adjust the limit via the python eval command

Comment: @Razetime Unfortunately, the problem on TIO is that Jelly segfaults if it recurses too much: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8f3jj/0cNMw8vP7wcSNUeWnpyOphreKzr4c7Z9o8aZtQ@3LHdHqhmTnFlsV5xaklRanJpUXFmfl5OZm5miYahgo2NgrGB5qOGuUcnhQH1AJUfXv7/v/F/cwA "Jelly – Try It Online"), whereas it doesn't when run locally

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 56 bytes (14 instructions)

```
5A000003 23000101 F8010000 27000001 5A010003 E3010001 F1FFFFFA
FE020004 23040001 27050101 FB03FFF6 F6040002 C9010003 F1FFFFF3
```

## Disassembly and explanation

```
ack PBNZ  $0,0F     // if(!m) {
    ADDU  $0,$1,1   //   m = n + 1
    POP   1,0       //   return m }
0H  SUBU  $0,$0,1   // m = m - 1
    PBNZ  $1,0F     // if(!n) {
    SETL  $1,1      //   n = 1
    JMP   ack       //   return ack(m,n) }
0H  GET   $2,rJ     // x = retaddr (to avoid trampling)
    ADDU  $4,$0,1   // m' = m + 1
    SUBU  $5,$1,1   // n' = n - 1
    PUSHJ $3,ack    // a = ack(m',n')
    PUT   rJ,$2     // retaddr = x
    SET   $1,$3     // n = a
    JMP   ack       // return ack(m,n)
```

There's hefty use here of tail recursion optimization, not that that'll help much (four words of stack are used here for every time we don't tail recurse, and the stack segment only holds \$2^{58}\$ words).

Answer (score 0):

### J : 50

```
>:@]`(1$:~<:@[)`(<:@[$:[$:_1+])@.(0>.[:<:@#.,&*)M.
```

Returns in a fraction of a second for 0...3 vs 0 ... 10:

```
   A=:>:@]`(1$:~<:@[)`(<:@[$:[$:_1+])@.(0>.[:<:@#.,&*)M.
   timespacex 'res=:(i.4) A"0 table (i.11)'
0.0336829 3.54035e6
   res
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────────┐
│A"0│0  1  2  3   4   5   6    7    8    9   10│
├───┼──────────────────────────────────────────┤
│0  │1  2  3  4   5   6   7    8    9   10   11│
│1  │2  3  4  5   6   7   8    9   10   11   12│
│2  │3  5  7  9  11  13  15   17   19   21   23│
│3  │5 13 29 61 125 253 509 1021 2045 4093 8189│
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

PS: the "0 serves to make A work on each single element, instead of gobbling up the left and right array, and generating length errors. But it's not needed for eg. 9 = 2 A 3 .

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40174/48934 You have been beaten!

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell: <s>81</s> 69 bytes

```
a::Int->Int->Int
a 0 n=n+1
a m 0=a (m-1) 1
a m n=a (m-1) a m (n-1)
```

`a 3 10` takes about 45 seconds.

Comment: this is code golf, so you should try to have the shortest code possible. for example, remove unnecessary spaces and the explicit type

Comment: you're also missing the parens on the fourth line

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 65

```ruby
h,a={},->m,n{h[[m,n]]||=m<1?(n+1):(n<1?a[m-1,1]:a[m-1,a[m,n-1]])}
```

### Explanation

This is a pretty straightforward translation of the algorithm given in the problem description.

- Input is taken as the arguments to a lambda. Two `Integer`s are expected.
- For speed and avoiding stack-overflow errors, answers are memoized in the `Hash` `h`. The `||=` operator is used to calculate a value that wasn't previously calculated.

`a[3,10]` is calculated in ~0.1 sec on my machine.

Here's an ungolfed version

```ruby
h = {}
a = lambda do |m,n|
  h[[m,n]] ||= if m < 1 
    n + 1
  elsif n < 1
    a[m-1,1]
  else
    a[m-1,a[m,n-1]]
  end
end
```

Comment: `a[3,10]` throw a SystemStackError on my machine...

Comment: Golf nitpicks: You could change `m<1?(n+1):(n<1?a[m-1,1]:a[m-1,a[m,n-1]])` to `m<1?n+1:a[m-1,n<1?1:a[m,n-1]]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse15), <s>99</s> 83 bytes

```
$Y1%j:j.0=m:2%k:k.0=n:m.n.>[k.1+!|m.n.<[#Y,j.1-,1;|m.n.*0=[#Y,j.1-,#Y,j.,k.1+;;]]]@
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 274 bytes

```
import java.math.*;class a{BigInteger A(BigInteger b,BigInteger B){if(b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))return B.add(BigInteger.ONE);if(B.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))return A(b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),BigInteger.ONE);return A(b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE),A(b,B.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));}}
```

It calculates `A(3,10)` in a few seconds, and given infinite memory and stack space, it can calculate any combination of `b` and `B` as long as the result is below 2<sup>2147483647</sup>-1.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can golf this to **185 bytes**: `import java.math.*;BigInteger A(BigInteger b,BigInteger B){return b.equals(B.ZERO)?B.add(B.ONE):B.equals(B.ZERO)?A(b.subtract(B.ONE),B.ONE):A(b.subtract(B.ONE),A(b,B.subtract(B.ONE)));}`

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 53 bytes

I tried to put the pattern matching in an if statement; turns out that makes the program longer...

```erlang
a(0,N)->N+1;a(M,0)->a(M-1,1);a(M,N)->a(M-1,a(M,N-1)).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCgIhEIbvPsV0WFDSRalTC75BnrpFxLDZJmwa6tLjm@uhIBj@f@Y7fGPjjH4SNo3RvXIhBankhglttmpAeuSy7rWF4oo1YL6gXUIx1pcOTkv0CcKSIT9wDZegzhz8ZOOGdPAv/nlGTBYMhDtIodVwbbyZrb@xnpAnOk/PFwZCgwuHd3TZUqQ7vl9/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
?ßUÉ!V´ªß:VÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=P99VySFWtKrfOlbE&input=MywxMA)

```
?ßUÉ!V´ªß:VÄ     :Implicit input of integers U=m & V=n
?                :If U is not 0
 ß               :Recursive call with arguments
  UÉ             :  U-1 and
    !V´          :  Logical NOT of postfix decremented V
       ª         :  Logical OR with
        ß        :  Recursive call with arguments U and the now decremented V
         :VÄ     :Else return V+1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.11, 96 bytes

```python
def a(m,n):
    if m==0:return n+1
    elif n==0:return a(m-1,1)
    else:return a(m-1,a(m,n-1))
```

Ungolfed:

```python
def a(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif n == 0:
        return a(m-1, 1)
    else:
        return a(m-1, a(m, n-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 110 B

To prevent death-by-boredom victims, the [boilerplate recursive definition](https://RosettaCode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Pascal) has been omitted.
Using the boilerplate recursive definition as reference, you can *save 1 byte* in code length by doing the following:

- *Presume* the `m = 0` case the default case.
  Do not wrap it in an `if` statement, just calculate `A ≔ n + 1` (and possibly *overwrite* this value).
- This necessitates a different expression for the `m ≠ 0 ∧ n = 0` situation.
  The following code uses sets: `[n] − [m] = [0]`.
  It means, take the `integer` set consisting of the single element `n`, remove from it all elements found in the second set (`[m]`) and compare the resulting `set` value against the set `[0]`.
- The fallback can be phrased as `n × m > 0`.
  Recall that any product is zero as soon as at least one factor is zero.
  Phrasing the fallback like this is necessary, because there are no `else` clauses.

```pascal
function A(m,n:integer):integer;begin
A:=n+1;if[n]-[m]=[0]then A:=A(m-1,1);if n*m>0 then A:=A(m-1,A(m,n-1))end
```

NB:
The limits of `integer` are implementation-defined.
For example, the [GNU Pascal Compiler](https://www.GNU-Pascal.de/) implementation will require the `‑‑setlimit=8189` parameter (or larger) to work correctly for \$m \leq 3\$, \$n \leq 10\$ test cases (beside the fact of having sufficient memory).