# Golf the fast growing hierarchy

Tags: code-golf, sequence

The [fast growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) is a way of categorizing how fast functions are growing,
defined the following way (for finite indices):

- \$ f_0(n)=n+1 \$
- \$ f_k(n)=f_{k-1}^n(n)\$ with \$f^n\$ meaning repeated application of the function f

### Examples

```
f0(5) = 6
f1(3) = f0(f0(f0(3))) = 3+1+1+1= 6
f2(4) = f1(f1(f1(f1(4)))) = 2*(2*(2*(2*4))) = 2⁴*4 = 64
f2(5) = f1(f1(f1(f1(f1(5))))) = ... = 2⁵*5 = 160
f2(50) = f1⁵⁰(50) = ... = 2⁵⁰*50 = 56294995342131200
f3(2) = f2(f2(2)) = f2(f2(2^2*2))) = f2(8) = 2^8*8 = 2048
f3(3) = f2(f2(f2(3))) = f2(f2(2³*3)) = f2(2²⁴*24)=2⁴⁰²⁶⁵³¹⁸⁴*402653184 = ...
f4(1) = f3(1) = f2(1) = f1(1) = f0(1) = 2
f4(2) = f3(f3(2)) = f3(2048) = f2²⁰⁴⁸(2048) = ...
...
```

shortcuts:

```
f1(n) = f0(...f0(n))) = n+n*1 = 2*n
f2(n) = f1(... f1(n)...)  = 2^n * n
```

Your goal is to write a program of function that given two positive integers \$k\$ and \$n\$ outputs \$f_k(n)\$

### Rules

- Given unlimited time and using unbounded integer types the *algorithm* you program is using should compute the correct result of f_k(n) for arbitrarily large `n` and `k` (even if the program will not finish in the lifetime of the universe)
- Your *program* only has to work for values that fit in a signed 32-bit integer
- Supporting the case \$k=0\$ is optional
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest solution in bytes wins

Comment: Is `Supporting the case =0 is optional` correct? Shouldn't it read `n=0` instead? `k=0` is the recursion base, so you can't exclude it meaningfully.

Comment: @SUTerliakov We can, since we know `f1(n)=2n`. Also, the domain is previously specified to be *positive* integers \$k,n\$.

Comment: Ough, I missed the *positive* specifier in your question, it saves 6 bytes, thanks! Linked Wikipedia article allows `n == 0` (with standard identity function \$ f^0(x) = x \$ for `n == 0`), so I didn't expect to find such relaxation in this question.

Comment: Is it okay if our program dies in `k >= 3` due to... compilation errors?

Comment: @UndoneStudios depends on the compilation error, anything about numbers/recursion depths being to large is okay. The important thing is that the algorithm theoretically works for larger k

Comment: What about syntax errors due to deeply nested parenthesis?

Comment: @UndoneStudios Also OK, falls under "numbers" (of nesting levels) being too large

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 16 bytes

```
{{y x/y}x}/[;1+]
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6qurlSo0K+srajVj7Y21I7l4kqLNoiNNo0F0oax0cYg2ig22gRKg8WNY4FMIG0SC1QCALztE+o=)

A curried function that takes `k` and then `n`. Call it as `f[k][n]`. (`f[k;n]` doesn't work.)

The trick here is to iterate directly on the function `f`. The formula \$f_k(n) = f_{k-1}^{n}(n)\$ can be seen as a transformation on a function \$f_{k-1}\$ to \$f_k\$. Given a function `x` (\$f_{k-1}\$) and input value `y` (\$n\$), \$f_k(n)\$ can be written as `y x/y`, and `{y x/y}x` is the partially applied function \$f_k\$ that we want. We can iterate this transformation `k` times to \$f_0\$ (`1+`) to get \$f_k\$. However, `k{y x/y}/(1+)` invokes a wrong overload of `/` because `{y x/y}` itself is syntactically dyadic. So I put it in `{...x}` to make it monadic.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your take on a J answer.  I have one idea using recursive reductions which I haven't implemented yet, but the problem is tricky in J if you want to approach it using higher order fns, because then you need to implement a recursive conjunction, and my attempt there ended in a stack error.  Would love to see any other better ideas.

Comment: I've added my recursive reduce solution.  There must be a shorter approach though.

Answer (score 5):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 18 bytes

```
4A 78 0C 51 89 C1 E8 F5 FF FF FF E2 F9 59 48 40 42 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJNb9swDIbP0q9gMwSQZmfIkh5aO94OO@@y04BlCBRZjpnZciDbmfP11@tR7leGXqqDSEp8H5KC9GSjdd@rugQBP0aCZxFLjQaTdpxtazhytmvrHIymuKz23gnBqI67iGlVFJBxVlTVDhxlkhkSBwLlHCOG9tF9dDzVmYbLkYz5aqWaxuG6bcxqJYQzm51ypZhJKQFtA5nw@59wCKyMYV9hCkbIuP9AtKJNDSzqJsXqU/6F@6RSoRWSn6gVR3EmRnD2lVhWORhoW0jgc0zmJoF7skEgOVytF934FkchbL34@WxpJ8Hknev/qkhVpzGZRQJzsr4qoy6v0GM8Uz30MuYlBZbYkIykpIGvMIMI7vzt21mIOqQ/zcNeuU9jZGIbovTsy/U4S/td6RytAV2lJhp69uDOtxvCgcK0gtMrbDr7SbRDIkRra9xYk4LOlfsoM/mrC4LfMr7A3xwLA@LgX3jafZtfvyCIMcL60JhaLi2ROn9J/6F1lt6HX/oHnRVqU/eTcj6jjb5lQkpT/AM)

Following the `regparm` calling convention, this takes *n* in EAX and *k* in EDX, and returns a number in EAX. For easier recursion, this function also preserves the values of EDX and ECX (ending with them unchanged).

In assembly:

```
f:  dec edx         # Subtract 1 from k in EDX.
    js z            # Jump if the result is negative (k was 0).
    push ecx        # Save the value of ECX onto the stack.
    mov ecx, eax    # Set ECX to n. This will be the iteration count.
r:  call f          # Recursive call, to apply fₖ₋₁ to EAX.
    loop r          # Subtract 1 from ECX and jump back to repeat if it's nonzero.
    pop ecx         # Restore the value of ECX from the stack.
    dec eax         # Subtract 1 from EAX, cancelling out the next instruction.
z:  inc eax         # Add 1 to n in EAX.
    inc edx         # Add 1 to EDX, restoring the value of k.
    ret             # Return.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 19 bytes

```
{y$[x;o@x-1;]/y+~x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6quVImusM53qNA1tI7Vr9Suq6jl4kqLNrA2jQVShtbGIMrI2gRCAQX1FcAMA5CAsbURRMAYos7E2hDCNwFKAACwYxhf)

```
{y$[x;o@x-1;]/y+~x}    / function with arguments x:k, y:n
  $[x;o@x-1;]          / if x>0, f_(k-1), else identity function
 y           /         / Apply the selected function n times to:
              y+~x     /   n + [0=k]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>96 79 70 69 63 61 59</s> 58  bytes

```py
g=lambda k,n:-~n*(k<1)or eval(f"({'n:=g(k-1,n),'*n})")[-1]
```

It takes time to compute k=2, n=50, but it should be completed after some time...

While this answer is longer, I'm keeping it because it inspired the other two winning answers in Python:

> <s>70 67</s> 65 bytes if Python could handle huge nested parentheses ([this answer is allowed, but other golfs based on this are already present](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264852/golf-the-fast-growing-hierarchy#comment578646_264852), with the other answers being [this one by xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264860/110681), and [this other one by SUTerliakov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264926/110681)):
> `f=lambda k,n:n+1if k>1else eval(f"{n*('f(%d,'%(k-1))}{n}{')'*n}")`

Comment: The lambda version can be 68 bytes by replacing `if not k else` with `if k==0else`

Comment: @noodleman Or even `k<1`.

Comment: `n+1` can be `~-n` and same as above, `not k` with `k<1`. I would also assume you could do maybe do something like `for i in range(n):n=g(k-1,n)` instead?

Comment: @JoKing `~-n` is `n-1`, not `n+1`. `~-1 == 0`, `~-2 == 1`.

Comment: Can be golfed to [62](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37dJtcxJzk1ISFbJ18qw0ovNitaPzrGzTNbJ1DXXyNNPyixTiFTLzog1itfJiNaN1DWMz0xSyFVJzilMV8rQNoaaUJxYXpxaVKKRrGOiYairY2iqYccGFDHWM0YWMdEwgQibIYhCdhmYGCEFjHSOwoJGBiQVC1ETHECIKsR7mGQA) (function name is important, so not 60). And [70](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY33VJS0xTSNbJ18jStuBQy0xSybQytilJLSovyFPK0DbkU0vKLFDIVMvMUihLz0lM1gMrybIHqdQ2BOrgUYCqhppUnFhenFpUADTTQMdVUsLVVMOOCCxnqGKMLGemYQIRMkMUgOg3NDBCCxjpGYEEjAxMLhKiJjiFEFGI9zFMA) with your function just by removing redundant `else`.

Comment: And to [53](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3TdNtcxJzk1ISFbJ18qyyFRLzUqLzrGzTNbJ1DXXyNNPyixTiFTLzog1itfJio3UNY_OLdOvyoJrLE4uLU4tKFNI1DHRMNRVsbRXMuOBChjrG6EJGOiYQIRNkMYhOQzMDhKCxjhFY0MjAxAIhaqJjCBGFWA_zAwA) assuming \$ n \gt 0 \$ (as pointed out by OP, \$ n = 0 \$ doesn't have to be supported here)

Comment: You can post that on your own, I'm opting to support `n`=0 because my current answer supports it

Comment: @STerliakov right, sorry, i meant `-~n`. always get that mixed up

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 38 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮＷ⊖Ｌυ«≔⊟υθ≔⊟υη¿η«Ｆθ⊞υ⊖η⊞υθ»⊞υ⊕θ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY67CsIwFIbn5CnOeAJ1KTh1El0Ekb5CradNIE3bXHSQPntMCtLi@t@@v5WNbcdGx9iNFrAUUAcnMRRwNVPw9zA8yKIQFX9LpQnwQq2lgYynJ97I9D6FhRDw4ezknOoN1uOUpALmVPrXZNZUByjXBluh8wbdr8tMZexnrXMLZ6Qd7U5u@TnnF15bZTyeG@fzsSrGEo7x8NJf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮ
```

Push `k` and `n` to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｗ⊖Ｌυ«
```

Repeat until the list only contains one value.

```
≔⊟υθ≔⊟υη
```

Extract `k` and `n` for the deepest recursion depth.

```
¿η«
```

If `k` is non-zero, then...

```
Ｆθ⊞υ⊖η
```

... push `n` copies of `k-1`, representing the recursive calls...

```
⊞υθ
```

... and push `k` back as the argument.

```
»⊞υ⊕θ
```

Otherwise just push `n` incremented as the result of `f0(n)`.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Output the final value.

52 bytes for a version optimised for `k<3`:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮＷ⊖Ｌυ«≔⊟υθ≔⊟υη≡η⁰⊞υ⊕θ¹⊞υ⊗θ²⊞υ×Ｘ²θθ«Ｆθ⊞υ⊖η⊞υθ»»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/NCsIwEITP7VPsMYEKWvBiT6IXQaQHXyDGbRNIU5sfexCfPSYVqQq7l5lZZj8umOE9UyE0vQFSUqi9FcQXcNA3706@u6AhlFb5KKRCIHvkBjvUDq/kiLp1MUwphUeeba2VrSZ1f4tSAUM8@tdE0uwoHRdAxHTFmUVYbr5654IhFb8Tqzmx7/1F/brl7J5lhzYWjvHvMn2RNgWv2DCv3CaVZhPtMNN@Y4kpnn2sieOZ5pnXRmpHdsy6RF2FUMJ6GRZ39QI) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
Nest[fNest[f,#,#]&,#+1&,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCQ67f2khRCGjrKOcqyajrK2oRqI8T@gKDOvJLpaWblW1y4tWjnWQdkoVs3BwaGaq9pAx7RWh6vaUMcYRBnpmEAosKCxjhGIMtExrOWq/Q8A)

Input `[k][n]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 24 bytes

```
>:@]`(<:@[$:^:]])@.(0<[)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrscPOyiE2QcPGyiFaxSrOKjZW00FPw8AmWhMifTNIkys1OSNfwUzBFqg1TcEUyjUB8o2AfBMI39DMACoAVWBkYGIBFDEGihhBRYBcEyDXEGLyggUQGgA)

*-4 thanks to Bubbler for this straightforward approach*

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
>:@]`(]$:/@,~]#_1+[)@.(0<[)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsdvOyiE2QSNWxUrfQacuVjneUDta00FPw8AmWhOi4maQJldqcka-gpmCLVB3moIplGsC5BsB-SYQvqGZAVQAqsDIwMQCKGIMFDGCigC5JkCuIcTkBQsgNAA)

*-1 using thanks to Bubbler's `0<]` instead of `0=]` idea*

This approach conceives uses a reduction which expands its left argument in place recursively:

```
2 f 3
1 1 1 f 3
1 1 0 0 0 f 3
1 1 0 0 f 4
1 1 0 f 5
1 1 f 6
1 0 0 0 f 6
... etc ...
```

And this is what the above code does:

- `@.(0=[)` If the left arg is 0...
- `(1+])` Return 1.  Otherwise...
- `]#_1+[` Repeat "left arg minus 1" as many times as the right arg...
- `]...,~` Prepend the right arg...
- `$:/@` And continue reducing the result using this fn.

Comment: Cool idea, but unfortunately [following the definition more directly is shorter.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYyxCsIwFEX3fMWrVpLQNia1lvbRSlBwEoeuIVoQi7i46OqPuNTBj-rfGEiGx-McLufzvY_Too5Q2TLCmlIyE3SAFoFCChLQXSZg1x32v9dzyKoJN6htzxrUJsYTWsu1YLIxnMBxKwizMS51-rbzs0oM75lK_KI1PBQ6Tq6X2wNKaF19gHXAwnHuuPCsShlEGOSyqJxZOZMH47BwqHx5HP3_Aw)

Comment: Right, good point... I think I got thrown off in my thinking because I was originally trying to find a solution that actually return a fn, but that's not why my current answer is doing anyway, and I think a misreading of the OP's task anyway.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 15 bytes

```
'>:'".@,'^:]'&,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FNVUtFK8NYM0UrS3V1LiU99TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsV7dzkpdSc9BRz3OKlZdTQciejNGkys1OSNfwUzBFqgjTUHdVB0qYAIUMQKJmEBFDM0MYEIwRUYGJhZAMWOQmBFMDChgAhIwVIfYsWABhAYA)

Takes `k` on the left as a number, and `n` on the right as a string.

Without `".@`, the function constructs the expression `>:^:]^:] ... ^:]n` as a string, where `^:]` is repeated `k` times.

`f^:]n` applies `f` `n` times to the initial value `n`. \$f_0\$ is increment, which is `>:`. \$f_1(n) = f_0^n(n)\$ is `>:^:]n`. In general, \$f_k(n) = f_{k-1}^n(n)\$ can be expressed as `(f_{k-1})^:]n`, and expanded recursively down to `k=0`, we get the expression above.

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ẋ@⁾¹¡”‘;v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//4bqLQOKBvsK5wqHigJ3igJg7dv///zL/NQ)

The same strategy applied to Jelly. `‘` (increment) plus `¹¡` (repeat *argument* times) repeated `k` times, evaluated and applied to `n`.

Comment: Really clever on the J one.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 50 bytes

```r
f=function(k,n){if(k)for(i in 1:n)n=f(k-1,n);n+!k}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYo7CoNAEEB7TzFiM4MTcP00igdIlSY3CBkYlsyCWSvx7Ouq1YP33pKSzLLaJ2ow9Gy0qaAnCQsqqIEbjWzO6uFynKwu/Z4EGx6oEHTcnWi5v5FldbEhqCDq7/uHsEYIBu/nKy8dt@fZs6N0AA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 39 bytes

A shorter version with a single recursive function suggested by [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

```javascript
f=(k,n,i=n)=>k*i?f(k-1,f(k,n,i-1)):n+!k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5RCsIwEET/PcX6t4lpm03TUoToTQRRI7WSior/3kkv5EVq2kRBSwZmM8s89rC@rS@bc326Jq7d7rrOGmyEE7VxzCwaXi8tNgkJG9KEGJu72bTpNq27tMddemz3aFEKKBiDLINy8rshAXnYWIlB/s/AQD6j/plRRQnQsUL4lY@GmuL4kY7J6/7g2g@lHpOKMcmrYJGWpmkgPHnhByrlHyIXoCJCoZcaanFeKa7YJ6iGW1YVr3qXuvojaQEUSTlSLAWn6DK46t4)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

```javascript
f=(k,n)=>k--?(g=i=>f(k,--i?g(i):n))(n):n+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5RCsIwEET/PcV@7sakTdK0FCH1JoKoLbWSior/3kkv5EVqbKKgJQOzmWUeu19f1@fNqT1ehOu3u2GoLXbcka06IZbY2NZWtU@EaJcNtrRwROi8zdWw6d25P@ySQ99gjZJDTgRpCsXsd6M4ZGFTSwzyfwIL2Vy9n51UNAcTKwq/8tFY0ww/MjF53u7M@KEwU1I@JXnlFGlJkgTCg@V@UIX8Q2QcdERo9NJjLc4rzTR9gnK8ZVWy8u3SlH8kw0FFUoYqloKr6DK4Hl4)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (k, n) => // f is a recursive function taking (k, n)
k-- ?         // if k is not 0 (decrement it afterwards):
  ( g = i =>  //   g is another recursive function taking a counter i
    f(        //   do a recursive call to f:
      k,      //     pass the updated value of k
      --i ?   //     decrement i, if it's not 0:
        g(i)  //       use the result of a recursive call to g for n
      :       //     else:
        n     //       final call: use n
    )         //   end of recursive call to f
  )(n)        //   initial call to g with i = n
:             // else (k = 0):
  n + 1       //   f0(n) = n + 1
```

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY5RCsIwEET/PcX6t4lpm03TUoToTQRRI7WSior/3kkv5EVq2kRBSwZmM8s89rC@rS@bc326Jq7d7rrOGmyEE7VxzCwaXi8tNgkJG9KEGJu72bTpNq27tMddemz3aFEKKBiDLINy8rshAXnYWIlB/s/AQD6j/plRRQnQsUL4lY@GmuL4kY7J6/7g2g@lHpOKMcmrYJGWpmkgPHnhByrlHyIXoCJCoZcaanFeKa7YJ6iGW1YVr3qXuvojaQEUSTlSLAWn6DK46t4)

Comment: @att Nice! (My initial attempt was close to that, but I messed it up and changed my mind.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
0%n=n+1
k%n=iterate((k-1)%)n!!n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/30A1zzZP25ArG0hnlqQWJZakamhk6xpqqmrmKSrm/c9NzMxTsFUoKMrMK1FQUTBSNf0PAA)

Writing out the definition.

**34 bytes**

```hs
q((>>=)id.q)(+1)
q=((!!).).iterate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQvacwSJghEgpajidpI6YlWfg7f9N7l223T4kD7VwAjCGMhy4I04KiEMAwoEYdu6@2ewaFFMRj4ytJ5hrfLke5qo0/F5I9G88u5x8)

A pointfree mess.

Comment: Fun 32, kinda stretching sequence IO: `l=(1+):[\n->iterate f n!!n|f<-l]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,n:k and eval(n*'f(k-1,'+'n'+')'*n)or-~n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P802JzE3KSVRIVsnzypbITEvRSG1LDFHI09LPU0jW9dQR11bPQ@INdW18jTzi3Tr8v4XFGXmlWikaRjpmGpq/gcA)

Based on the [second solution of UndoneStudios](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264855/20260). In practice gives a `MemoryError` for larger values from trying to generate huge strings of Python code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
x@’ßƒ⁸ʋ‘⁹?
```

A dyadic Link that accepts \$n\$ on the left and \$k\$ on the right and yields \$f_k(n)\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9qZWxsef//eEDigJnDn8aS4oG4yovigJjigbk/////Nf8y)**

#### How?

```
x@’ßƒ⁸ʋ‘⁹? - Link: integer, n; integer, k
         ? - if...
        ⁹  - ...condition: chain's right argument, k -> k > 0?
      ʋ    - ...then: last four links as a dyad - g(n, k):
  ’        -            decrement {k} -> k-1
 @         -            with swapped arguments:
x          -              {k-1} repeated {n} times -> [k-1,k-1,...,k-1]
     ⁸     -            chain's left argument, n
    ƒ      -            reduce {[n, k-1,k-1,...,k-1]} by:
   ß       -              {current value} this Link {next value}
       ‘   - ...else: increment {n} -> n+1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 41 bytes

```
f(k,n,i=n)=if(k*i,f(k-1,f(k,n,i-1)),n+!k)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWNzXTNLJ18nQybfM0bTOBbK1MHSCpa6gDFdc11NTUydNWzNaEakhKLCjIqdRIVNC1Uygoyswr0UiMNoxVUNJRUFJIjDYCskAySgppYHEdsBjQCIXoaAMdUyA_2lDHGEQZ6ZhAKLCgsY4RiDLRMYyNhdoEcyIA)

A port of [@Arnauld's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264858/9288).

---

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 49 bytes

```
f(k,n,i)=if(i,f(k,f(k,n,i-1)),k,f(k-1,n,n-1),n+1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY49CgIxEEavMqRK8AvsZFew0YuEILGIBCWEZS08i802smfyNiYxVt-8N8zPa8t-judrXtf3Ywn68OEgb0iI6hiDjKjUjWal0Ehz4VQYaceqD158zven9KRPlOeYFuktOxIgQd6aUtWOoNA8misLydoB-8KWMdYwmH7R5AhTYwI71y_9X_0C)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.11/), 53 bytes

```python
g=lambda k,n:k and[n:=g(k-1,n)for _ in[0]*n][-1]or-~n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3TdNtcxJzk1ISFbJ18qyyFRLzUqLzrGzTNbJ1DXXyNNPyixTiFTLzog1itfJio3UNY_OLdOvyoJrLE4uLU4tKFNI1DHRMNRVsbRXMuOBChjrG6EJGOiYQIRNkMYhOQzMDhKCxjhFY0MjAxAIhaqJjCBGFWA_zAwA)

Does not support \$ n = 0 \$; supports \$ k = 0 \$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
f=->k,n{k>0?n.times{n=f[k-1,n]}:n+=1;n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5bJ686287APk@vJDM3tbg6zzYtOlvXUCcvttYqT9vW0Dqv9n@BQlq0gY5pLBeIYahjDGEY6ZjAGEApZSjLACJmrGMEFTOGqTfRMYQKmQAl/wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>51</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```c
f(k,n,i){for(i=n;k*i--;)n=f(k-1,n);k=n+!k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7NDoIwEITvfYoVA2m1NfJ3qvVJvJCWSlNcDGA8EJ69FhIn2cPufDNZLZ5ah2Cp58gdW@wwUqdQ@pMTQjJU0RE5Rya9wvPByzUcHer@Y1q4TbNxw6W7E@JwhlfjkDJYCERtB88B5b59O9e3dNINWpqkBlLzwIRDFokMGSgFBdvBTe8xhiNnU0NTE90/vvVx2F4FZEySNVyhJjmUpIAqTk1KKEgF@Q8)

5 bytes shaved off thanks to the `n+!k` trick I saw others do, and 3 more thanks to c-- :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 92 bytes

```
({}<>)(()){{}((){[()](<({}[()])<>(({})<>){({}[()]<(({}))>)}{}{}>)}{}){({}<>{})(<>)}{}([])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYkxCoBADAS/Yrlb2Ah2IR85rjgLQRQL25C3xxhkixlmt2cc97xf44yAuSgB0swT1sAOyfwJRZGaoP1JKlDplivUJ5oCqYDWmSFimdYX)

Supports \$k=0\$ and \$n=0\$.  Large outputs take an unreasonable amount of time to compute, since no shortcuts are taken for \$f_1\$ or \$f_2\$.